# create multiple default value rows in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g

```
select 'a' as st,'x' as ed from dual
union all
select 'b' as st,'y' as ed from dual
union all
select 'c' as st,'z' as ed from dual
```

Instead can we write some thing like using directly with pivot/unpivot
and connect by cclause in one slect statement

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this assuming you just want consecutive characters in consecutive rows

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select chr( ascii('a') + level - 1) st,
  2         chr( ascii('x') + level - 1) ed
  3    from dual
  4* connect by level <= 3
SQL> /

ST   ED
---- ----
a    x
b    y
c    z
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Justin.Sorry I haven't asked you correctly.but some thing that is not in aorder.select 'work' as st,'mike' as ed from dual union all select 'office' as st,'rob' as ed from dual.CAn we write this.

Comment: @siddharth - If there is no way to generate the data and you're going to have to list out the data elements anyway, a bunch of UNION ALL's is going to be the simplest approach.  What problem are you trying to solve by coming up with a more complex way of specifying sample data?

Comment: I am tryingto get default values if the select query didn't return any rows.I knew we can use not exits but I don't want my query to run again to check if it returns or not.I am doing this UNION ALL and always adding these values and doing group by on my report.

Comment: @siddharth - I'm not sure that I follow but this sounds to me very different than the question you asked initially.  Perhaps you could either edit your question or ask a new question that explains in more detail what problem you're trying to solve?